# Open Source Annotation Tools for spaCy's Entity Linker?

Tags: spacy, entity-linking

According to the Tutorial "[Training a custom ENTITY LINKING model with spaCy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8u57WSXVpmw&ab_channel=Explosion)" (20:33) this is the training data format for spaCy's Entity Linker:

```
TRAIN_DATA = ("Emerson was born on a farm in Blackbutt, Queensland.", {"links": {(0, 7): { "Q312545": 1.0 }}})
```

My search for open source annotation tool is not successful. Do you know an open source/free annotation tool for this format?

Comment: Do the earlier parts of the video not show you how to setup and annotate data using spaCy's annotation tool Prodigy?

Comment: Yes with Prodigy. But it is unfortunately not free or open-source (https://prodi.gy/docs/).

Comment: I would probably use a different open source annotation tool such as [doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano) to annotate your data and create a custom script to convert their format to the format spaCy expects.

Comment: It would work for me. Thank you!